# is MSI CR400 laptop compatible for SSD?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I have a laptop which model is MSI CR400, and the HDD is already faulty, I'm planning to buy a new one and give my old MSI CR400 to someone, so before giving it, I want to replace the faulty HDD with the new SSD, but I don't know if it is compatible.

Comment: Why was this downvoted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can upgrade the hard drive to an SSD.  This is true of the vast, vast majority of systems (there are a very few which have whitelists of acceptable hardware, but these are not the norm).

Looking at http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/MSI(MicroStar)/cr400  shows they will accept crucial SSD's - which means they will most likely accept any aftermarket SSD's [ at least any after-market SSD's which are not more then 2TB in size - there are some technical limitations of disks which are greater then 2TB which may make them incompatible]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is support, buy SSD with sata connection interface with SATA 3 Gb/s and with size 2.5”. I was used laptop before

Comment: Why was this downvoted ?